# expected valid? to return true, got false

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

I have below spec from rails tutorial by Michael Hartl and **it is working fine**
up to [6.2.3 Length validation](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-length_validation)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")}

  subject { @user}

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " "  }
    it { should_not be_valid  }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

After that on [6.2.4 Format validation](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-format_validation), when I added below code, **it is not working**

```
describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end


  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end
```

here is the complete file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")}

  subject { @user}

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " "  }
    it { should_not be_valid  }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end


  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the error log, any idea How can I fix it?

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
....................F.....F

Failures:

  1) User 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User when email format is valid should be valid
     Failure/Error: @user.should be_valid
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:45:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.4 seconds
27 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:41 # User when email format is valid should be valid

Randomized with seed 60820
```

Here is the Gemfile

```
cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.1.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.6'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  # gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end
```

and model file

```
$ cat app/models/user.rb 
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\W+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but could I suggest putting this in a GitHub repo. It makes it much easier for people to try reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AndyWaite good idea, let me do it. thanks this is really good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, I got a help from this link - [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570935/rails-3-tutorial-chapter-6-strange-rspec-failures)

I think it is my `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX` was wrong

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Actual is :

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Next time I will place code on github and place here a link, so that is